# Trace class operators convergent series

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

On wikipedia it is mentioned that if we are on some (separable) Hilbert space $H$ and there is an ONB $(e_n)$ such that any compact operator $K$ can be written as 
$$ K = \sum_{n,m =0}^{\infty} K_{n,m} e_n \otimes e_m.$$

This made me wonder whether the result is still true if $K$ is a trace-class operator and the convergence is assumed to be in trace-norm as well? Does anybody know this?

By the way, the article was [this one.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis#Bases_for_spaces_of_operators)

Comment: general point: when you talk about convergence of a doubly-indexed series, you should specify the actual limiting process https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Double_sequence (i.e. do you mean $\lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{m,n=0}^N$

Comment: yes, I mean precisely what you wrote

Comment: so your question can be paraphrase by asking whether every trace-class operator is a trace-norm limit of finite-rank operators?

Comment: @paulgarrett no. here the question is the converse, we are first given the ONB and represent the operator in this basis.I am asking whether this is possible.

Comment: That URL does not look right...

Comment: Yes, of course.  This is just the statement that $e_n\otimes e_m$ is, in its natural order, a shrinking basis for the compact operators on $\ell_2$.  Boundedness of the partial sum projections in the trace class norm follows by duality from the boundedness in the operator norm.